# How to play different sound files on local notifications

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, notifications

Local notifications pop up when my Xamarin phone app receives a new event. This works fine, and it also plays a sound. However I want to play different sounds depending on the type of event that my app has received. I thought this would be simple enough, but whatever sound is played first after I rebuild the app, that is the sound that then plays for every notification regardless of the code.

For example, after rebuild, if Priority enum is Priority.Temp then TempNotif.wav will play. But if the code calls this method again to show another notification and Priority enum isn't Priority.Temp, TempNotif.wav still plays, even though I have set it to play StandardNotif.wav. It seems like android takes a copy of the first sound and doesn't bother updating it once there is a sound in place. Whatever is happening, surely I can play different sounds for different notifcations?

Here is code:

```
public void CreateNotification(string title, string message, Priority priority)
    {
        Android.Net.Uri sound = null;

        if (priority == Priority.Temperature)
        {
            sound = global::Android.Net.Uri.Parse($!{ContentResolver.SchemeAndroidResource}://{context.PackageName}/{Resource.Raw.TempNotif}");
        }
        else
        {
            sound = global::Android.Net.Uri.Parse($!{ContentResolver.SchemeAndroidResource}://{context.PackageName}/{Resource.Raw.StandardNotif}");
        }

        var alarmAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .SetContentType(AudioContentType.Sonification)
            .SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Notification).Build();

        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, notificationChannelId);
        builder.SetContentTitle(title)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetContentText(message)
            .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.High)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.MetroIcon)
            .SetColor(00255)
            .SetVibrate(new long[0])
            .SetSound(sound)
            .SetVisibility((int)NotificationVisibility.Public);

        notificationManager = context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as 
NotificationManager;

        if (global::Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            NotificationImportance importance = NotificationImportance.High;

            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(notificationChannelId, 
title, importance);
            notificationChannel.Importance = NotificationImportance.High;
            notificationChannel.EnableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.EnableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.SetSound(sound, alarmAttributes);
            notificationChannel.SetShowBadge(true);
            notificationChannel.SetVibrationPattern(new long[] { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400 });

            if (notificationManager != null)
            {
                builder.SetChannelId(notificationChannelId);
                notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }
        }

        notificationManager.Notify(0, builder.Build());
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to override your notifications? If not try to pass unique id instead of passing always 0 when calling notificationManager.Notify(0, builder.Build());

Comment: Will check this when I'm back at the computer thanks bro

Comment: @DavidAndrewThorpe Notification.Builder setSound  method was deprecated in API level 26. Using NotificationChannel#setSound(Uri, AudioAttributes) instead. Please take a look:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSound(android.net.Uri,%20android.media.AudioAttributes)

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I'm using NotificationCompat.Builder which I think isn't depreciated?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT If you look at the lower half of my code, you will see that I am using NotificationChannel.SetSound() already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @Mooniean for the answer!

The answer is to provide a different channel ID for each type of notification I want to display.

I set two static values for channel ID's and provide one depending on the type of notification I want to display.

```
    private static string StandardchannelId = "1000";
    private static string TempChannelId = "2000";
```

Here I assign my channelID depending on an enum I made:

```
    if (priority == Priority.Temperature)
                {
                    this.channelId = TempChannelId;
                    sound = global::Android.Net.Uri.Parse($"{ContentResolver.SchemeAndroidResource}://{context.PackageName}/{Resource.Raw.TempNotif}");
                }
   else
               {
                   this.channelId = StandardchannelId;
                   sound = global::Android.Net.Uri.Parse($"{ContentResolver.SchemeAndroidResource}://{context.PackageName}/{Resource.Raw.StandardNotif}");
               }
```

And here I assign the channelID:

```
builder.SetChannelId(this.channelId);
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your issue now, please remember to mark your reply as answer, it may be helpful to other community members, thanks.